# Sometimes Parse doesn't fetch all objects of my Parse class (Images Downloading)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I download images from `Parse`, and sometimes the fetch result get more errores than images get. That's the code I use to download the images:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    *PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:albumToLoad];

    NSArray *objectsPFFounded=[NSArray arrayWithArray:[query findObjects]];

    int count= [objectsPFFounded count];

    int i=0;
    while (i<count){
        PFFile *userImageFile = [objectsPFFounded objectAtIndex:i][@"imageFile"];
        [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {

                if (!self.imagesGallery) {
                    self.imagesGallery = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
                }else{
                    [self.imagesGallery addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
                }

            }
        }];
        i++;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self updateCollectionViewWhenBackgroundDone];
        });
    });
```

I get as well this error from console:

```
    Could not save HTTP response body to /var/mobile/Applications/D96AFE9B-17EF-4630-8608-423D721394F3/Library/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/578df836-a12c-4e70-b389-033efa647ee5-28.jpg: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x16ed58a0 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Applications/D96AFE9B-17EF-4630-8608-423D721394F3/tmp/PFHTTPCommand0x16ddd220, NSUserStringVariant=( Move ), 
NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Applications/D96AFE9B-17EF-4630-8608-423D721394F3/tmp/PFHTTPCommand0x16ddd220, NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/D96AFE9B-17EF-4630-8608-423D721394F3/Library/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/578df836-a12c-4e70-b389-033efa647ee5-28.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x16ee8350 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
```

Have I to delete temp directory or cache directory before do the objects fetching? How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoa error 516 means that a file already exists. In your case, it seems that the image file already exists in the local cache.

You can try to check with `isDataAvailable()` first before you call `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`.

Also, I believe this is warning should be a bug in parse. Be sure you are using the latest version of the parse framework.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error occurred in the following case:

I loaded a `PFFile` the first time. It was loaded from the server, since it was not yet cached. During loading, caching was apparently going on.

While the file was still loading, it was requested again in a different context. Since caching was not yet completed, a server request was done again. This 2nd server request apparently initiated again to cache the file, and iOS complained with error 516 (file exists). The 2nd server request terminated thus with error without returning the file data. I consider this as a Parse bug.

The workaround I used was to store which file requests are under way, and to delay a new request to the same file a little to give the system a chance to complete writing the cache file. This worked.

A better way, of course, were to queue the requests for the same file so that further requests are only executed if the 1st one has completed, so that these requests are served from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to reload my Collection View in a incorrect thread. That's how looks my final code. It works like a charm

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

      PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:albumToLoad];

      [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
          if (!error){
              if (objects.count > 0){
                  for (PFObject *eachObject in objects){
                      PFFile *userImageFile = [eachObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
                      PFImageView *imageViewParse=[[PFImageView alloc] init];
                      imageViewParse.file=userImageFile;
                      [imageViewParse loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error){
                            if (!self.imagesGallery) {
                                  self.imagesGallery = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:image];
                            }else{
                                  [self.imagesGallery addObject:image];
                            }

                              if ([self.imagesGallery count] == objects.count){
                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                      [self updateCollectionViewWhenBackgroundDone];

                                  });
                              }
                          }
                      }];


                }

              }

          }
      }];

  });
```